# Custom typecast method for ActiveRecord object's attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is it possible to override the typecast of an attribute for an ActiveRecord object.  For instance

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  def name.to_s
    #some logic to act on self.name
  end
end
```

I know I could do this with a helper, but just was curious if this was possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just wanting to manipulate what name returns...do this...

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  def name
    this_name = read_attribute(:name)

    # do some stuff with this_name

    this_name #return this_name
  end
end
```

Comment: What I wanted to do was take a field that normally returns an integer and be able to call to_s on it and do a lookup and return the string equivalent.  So if the integer returns 1 then to_s returns "active."  Like I said, I know I can do this with helpers, but I wondered if you could do it at the model level.